# Invalid Language: 'fil' on 'hreflang'

Tags: php, html, zend-framework3, laminas

I'm trying to translate a website made with Laminas for Philippines in Filipino language and inform the search engines of this via the `rel="alternate"` and `hreflang="fil"` tags.

However, using several tools online to check if this is "ok" they will all say the same thing:

```
Invalid Language: fil
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) this is correct (or maybe I`m looking at the wrong place?).

On my website I want to use only generalised language codes, so for example I don't want to use "en-PH".

Tools I have used:

- https://dejanmarketing.com/flang/
- https://technicalseo.com/tools/hreflang/

To be honest I have tried several combinations like "ph", "phl", etc; but none of them are correct.

What might be the issue and why "fil" is incorrect language code for Philippines?

Answer (score 0):

if still relevant - hreflang="fl"

Comment: Where did you get that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).